# Javascript not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, scheduler

I am using dhtmlxscheduler in my application that uses javascript to handle userclick events. The application was working fine all the time, now it does not work in IE8 correctly. No code changes have been made. It works fine in IE7, IE8 compatibility mode and all other browsers. 
My question is , without any changes from our side, how could it be that the application javascript is not working properly in IE8 all of a sudden? Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >` in your `html head tag` and try. Switching the compatibility view on turns IE into IE7 rendering. You can check the link for compatibility reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SetMode

Comment: Yes do `IE=EmulateIE9`. I just did this change in my html and something that was working in IE8 compatibilty view now also works in IE8 standard view